# Wildcard subdomain mod-rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wildcard-subdomain

I have a wildcard subdomain `*.domain.com` assigned to public_html/.

I want to make the directory `www.domain.com/folder1/index.php?name=rock` to `rock.domain.com`.

As for another one, I want to make `www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/index.php?id=5` to `5.domain.com`

Are there any way to do this? I'm a beginner in mod-rewrite. Really appreciate your help. Thanks

**Additional Information**

I need both of them. They will have different variables.

For example, /folder1/index.php is based on state name(?state=statename).

For the /folder1/folder2/index.php, it will be based on unique name(?name=uniquename).

So, www.domain.com/folder1/index.php?state=statename will be statename.domain.com

and www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/index.php?name=uniquename will be uniquename.domain.com

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the htaccess file in your document root, you can add rules specific for "rock" and "5":

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^rock\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /folder1/index.php?name=rock [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^5\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /folder1/folder2/index.php?name=5 [L,QSA]
```

---

If you want it to redirect in the other direction then you'd need:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^state=(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^folder1/index\.php$ http://%1.domain.com/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^folder1/folder2/index\.php$ http://%1.domain.com/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you. But what if the rock and 5 will change based on php result. Another word, it's flexible and the word can be anything.

Comment: @RedzwanLatif how are you supposed to tell the difference between what goes to `/folder1/index.php` and what goes to `/folder1/folder2/index.php`?

Comment: It redirects back to domain.com instead of uniquename.domain.com. The other answers also do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Following generic rule should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+folder1/index\.php\?state=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1.domain.com/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+folder1/folder2/index\.php\?name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1.domain.com/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: do you want `/folder1/folder2/index.php` or `/folder1/index.php`?

Comment: I need both of them. They will have different variables. For example, /folder1/index.php is based on state name(?state=statename). For the /folder1/folder2/index.php, it will be based on unique name(?name=uniquename). So, www.domain.com/folder1/index.php?state=statename will be statename.domain.com and www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/index.php?name=uniquename will be uniquename.domain.com. Thank you

Comment: It redirects back to domain.com instead of uniquename.domain.com. The other answers also do the same.

Comment: What is the original URL you entered in your browser. Is it `http://www.domain.com/folder1/index.php?state=rock` ?